# Convert from Tensorflow -> CoreML 3.0 for slot/intent detection

Tags: python, swift, tensorflow, chatbot, coreml

I am trying to use some of the models created by this codebase ([Slot-Filling-Understanding-Using-RNNs](https://github.com/IsaacAhouma/Slot-Filling-Understanding-Using-RNNs)) in my Swift application.

I was able to convert `lstm_nopooling`, `lstm_nopooling300` and `lstm` to convert to CoreML.

In `model.py` I used this code:

```
def save_model(self):
    joblib.dump(self.summary, 'models/' + self.name + '.txt')
    self.model.save('models/' + self.name + '.h5')
    try:
        coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(self.model, input_names="main_input", output_names=["intent_output","slot_output"])
        coreml_model.save('models/' + self.name + '.mlmodel')
    except:
        pass
    print("Saved model to disk")
```

I am trying to convert the vectors back to an intent and slots.

I have this, but

```
    func tokenizeSentences(instr: String) -> [Int] {
        let s = instr.lowercased().split(separator: " ")
        var ret = [Int]()
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "atis.dict.vocab", ofType: "csv") {
            do {
                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
                print(contents)
                var lines = contents.split { $0.isNewline }
                var pos = 0
                for word in s {
                    if let index = lines.firstIndex(of: word) {
                        print(index.description + " " + word)
                        ret.append(index)
                    }
                }
                return ret
            } catch {
                // contents could not be loaded
            }
        } else {
            // example.txt not found!
        }
        return ret
    }
    func predictText(instr:String) {
        let model = lstm_nopooling300()
        guard let mlMultiArray = try? MLMultiArray(shape:[20,1,1],
                                                   dataType:MLMultiArrayDataType.int32) else {
                                                    fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. MLMultiArray")
        }
        let tokens = tokenizeSentences(instr: instr)
        for (index, element) in tokens.enumerated() {
            mlMultiArray[index] = NSNumber(integerLiteral: element)
        }

        guard let m = try? model.prediction(input: lstm_nopooling300Input.init(main_input: mlMultiArray))
            else {
                fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. MLMultiArray")
        }
        let mm = m.intent_output
        let length = mm.count
        let doublePtr =  mm.dataPointer.bindMemory(to: Double.self, capacity: length)
        let doubleBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: doublePtr, count: length)
        let output = Array(doubleBuffer)
        print("******** intents \(mm.count) ********")
        print(output)
        let mn = m.slot_output
        let length2 = mn.count
        let doublePtr2 =  mm.dataPointer.bindMemory(to: Double.self, capacity: length2)
        let doubleBuffer2 = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: doublePtr2, count: length2)
        let output2 = Array(doubleBuffer2)
        print("******** slots \(mn.count) ********")
        print(output2)
    }
}
```

When I run my code I get this, truncated, for intents:

> ******** intents 540 ********
>
> [0.0028914143331348896, 0.0057610333897173405, 4.1651015635579824e-05,
>   0.15935245156288147, 5.6665314332349226e-05, 5.7797817134996876e-05, 0.0044302307069301605, 0.00012486864579841495, 0.0004683282459154725, 0.003053907072171569, 3.806956738117151e-05, 0.012112349271774292, 5.861848694621585e-05, 0.0031344725284725428,

The problem, I believe, is that the ids are in a pickle file, so in atis/atis.train.pkl perhaps.

All I did was train the models and convert those I could to CoreML and now I am trying to use it, but not certain what to do next.

I have a textfield and I enter 'current weather in london' and I hope to get something similar to (this is from running example.py)
`{'intent': 'weather_intent', 'slots': [{'name': 'city', 'value': 'London'}]}`

Here is the coreml input/output

[image]

Comment: Which code did you run to produce that output?

Comment: @smac89 - I have an application I wrote that I am trying to use this in, and that is the code I ran. If you look at the swift code, 'print(output)' is what I displayed, but I only wanted to show a small part of the values returned. I added more code, as I forgot one function and showing all of it may help.

Comment: What does the model actually output? The original model.py shows that it takes an argmax to get an index and then looks something up in a table. From your question it's not clear what the output data looks like and how those argmax should be taken.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans - Thanks. Added what I typed and what I expect to get, or something close to it.

Comment: But I asked what you're actually getting from the model. How many outputs, what are their datatypes, what are their shapes, etc?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans - from model.py:
       main_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='main_input')
        slot_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_slots, activation='softmax'), name='slot_output')(x)
        intent_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'), name='intent_output')(x)
        model = kerasModel(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[intent_output, slot_output])

Comment: I was really hoping to see the output you're getting from the Core ML model, not the Keras one.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans - hopefully the image helps.

Comment: OK, so you have two multi-array outputs, one of size 27 and one of size 133. Now look at the shapes of the output tensors in the Python code and see if they match. Then, step through the Python code to see how they post-process those tensors, and do the same thing in your Swift code. This is not something that Core ML will handle for you.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans - The problem is that there is a pickle file being used, in https://github.com/IsaacAhouma/Slot-Filling-Understanding-Using-RNNs/tree/master/atis, and I am not certain how to use this.  That is what python is doing, it creates a dictionary from atis/atis.train.pkl. Do I just save this as a text file, then bring that into the project and read it?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans - Am I properly turning the multiarray into an array of Doubles? I think that is a big part of my problem.

Comment: You should save the pickle file into some kind of format that you can load from Swift. I don't see anything wrong about how you're turning the MLMultiArray into doubles. (I also think your question is way too broad for answering on Stack Overflow. This kind of work is usually what you'd hire someone to help you with, as there are many different steps involved.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MatthijsHollemans I was able to figure out what to do.

In data_processing.py I added these:

```
with open('atis/wordlist.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in ids2words.keys():
        f.write("%s\n"%(ids2words.keys[key]))
with open('atis/wordlist_slots.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in ids2slots.keys():
        f.write("%s\n"%(ids2slots[key]))
with open('atis/wordlist_intents.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in ids2intents.keys():
        f.write("%s\n"%(ids2intents[key]))
```

This allows me to tokenize correctly, using wordlist.csv.

Then when I get the response back, and using `mm.count` was wrong, it should have been `output.count` for example, I could see the intents.

Look for the element that has the largest value, and then you look up in wordlist_intents.csv (I turned this into an array, probably should be a dictionary) to find the likely intent.

I still need to do the slots, but the basic idea is the same.

The key was to output the dictionary used in python to a csv file and then import that into the project.

**UPDATE**

I realized that when mm.count was 540 that is because it can have 20 words in the sentence and so it can return that many.  So in my case I needed to split the word by space and then loop that many times as I won't get more slots than I have words.

I am doing this in SwiftUI so I also had to create an observable so I could use EnvironmentObject to pass in the terms.

So, to properly loop over the double array in memory I am including the latest code that does what I expect.

```
func predictText(instr:String) {
    let model = lstm_nopooling300()
    guard let mlMultiArray = try? MLMultiArray(shape:[20,1,1],
                                               dataType:MLMultiArrayDataType.int32) else {
                                                fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. MLMultiArray")
    }
    let tokens = tokenizeSentences(instr: instr)
    let sent = instr.split(separator: " ")
    print(instr)
    print(tokens)
    for (index, element) in tokens.enumerated() {
        mlMultiArray[index] = NSNumber(integerLiteral: element)
    }

    guard let m = try? model.prediction(input: lstm_nopooling300Input.init(main_input: mlMultiArray))
        else {
            fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. MLMultiArray")
    }

    let mm = m.intent_output
    let length = mm.count
    let doublePtr =  mm.dataPointer.bindMemory(to: Double.self, capacity: length)
    var intents = [String]()
    for i in 0...sent.count - 1  {
        let doubleBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: doublePtr + i * 27, count: 27)
        let output = Array(doubleBuffer)
        let intent = convertVectorToIntent(vector: output)
        intents.append(intent)
    }
    print(intents)
    let mn = m.slot_output
    let length2 = mn.count
    let doublePtr2 =  mn.dataPointer.bindMemory(to: Double.self, capacity: length2)
    var slots = [String]()
    for i in 0...sent.count - 1 {
        let doubleBuffer2 = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: doublePtr2 + i * 133, count: 133)
        let output2 = Array(doubleBuffer2)
        var slot = ""
        slot = convertVectorToSlot(vector: output2)
        slots.append(slot)
        slots.append(sent[i].description)
    }
    print(slots)
}
```